# Pasar un objeto serializado por un formulario

Tags: php, poo

Estoy intentando pasar un objeto `serializado` por un formulario, para recogerlo y no tenerlo que volver a crear en la siguiente página, pero no me imprime la cadena de forma correcta en el `input` en el que estoy imprimiendo. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
class Objeto{

    public $id;
    public $nombre;
    public $atributos;

    public function __construct($id, $nombre, $atributos){

        $this->id=$id;
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->atributos=$atributos;

    }

}

$objeto= new Objeto(32,'camiseta','de color verde');

$serializado=serialize($objeto);
?>
```

Luego tengo un formulario en el que imprimo el objeto serializado:

```
<form method="post" action="pasando-serializado.php" >
   <input type="text" name="serializado" value="<?php echo $cadena;?>" lenght=1000 style="width: 50%"/>
   <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y finalmente un archivo en el que recojo el post del formulario:

```
    $serializado=$_POST['serializado'];

$unserializado=unserialize($serializado);

echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($unserializado);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Me devuelve el valor "O:6".

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto? Se supone que si lo que te devuelve el `serialize` es una cadena la deberías poder imprimir donde quisieras, ¿no?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda ;-)

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el `HTML` se *"rompe"* al imprimir el resultado de [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php)

Por ejemplo, el resultado de [`$serializado=serialize($objeto);`](http://rextester.com/BETAW20010) es:

```
O:6:"Objeto":3:{s:2:"id";i:32;s:6:"nombre";s:8:"camiseta";s:9:"atributos";s:14:"de color verde";}
```

Al imprimir este valor en el `value` del `input`, este se corta al detectar la primer comilla doble (`"`). Demo:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('serializado').value)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="serializado" value="O:6:"Objeto":3:{s:2:"id";i:32;s:6:"nombre";s:8:"camiseta";s:9:"atributos";s:14:"de color verde";}" lenght=1000 style="width: 50%"/>
```

### Solución:

Podrias usar [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) para escapar los caracteres especiales y así evitar que se el `HTML` se *"rompa"*

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="serializado" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cadena);?>" lenght=1000 style="width: 50%"/>
```

Demo:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('serializado').value)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="serializado" value="O:6:&quot;Objeto&quot;:3:{s:2:&quot;id&quot;;i:32;s:6:&quot;nombre&quot;;s:8:&quot;camiseta&quot;;s:9:&quot;atributos&quot;;s:14:&quot;de color verde&quot;;}" lenght=1000 style="width: 50%"/>
```